# Multiple Modals, Can't Close?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

So implementing a few various modals in my web page. My code is as follows.

HTML

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times</span>
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
  <script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeSel")[0];
  btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  </script>
```

all very simple, my issue occurs when i try to add another modal, i change the id value, and add another script for the different modal, which works fine, but when it comes to actually closing the modal it wont work...
For the close button CSS im using the same class, is this what is causing the issue?

```
/* The close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-style: arial;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeSel")[0]` here u are using class name as `closeSel` but in html code `<span class="close">&times</span>` you are using class `close`

Comment: ah sorry Atal, i edited the variables so they are more simple for stackoverflow, that was just a typo

Comment: can you just create a jsfiddle reproducing your problem as it is not very clear from this code what may be the cause

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it would be the classes, I would think more along the IDs as they need to be unique, do you also change the button ID?
If the click and close functionality does not take any parameters, you could just use inline onclick html, then you would be more certain it is not IDs getting messed up.
In the code you are also referencing a class "closeSel" which I do not see in the HTML

Comment: I will try calling as a id instead of class, see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you need to iterate through each span element. I have attached a working example.

```
<!-- Test Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>First Test text in modal..</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Test Modal 2 -->
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Second test text in modal..</p>
      </div>
    </div>

<script>

      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
      var modal;
      var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button is-primary is-small modal-button");

      for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        var thisBtn = btn[i];
        thisBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
          modal = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
          modal.style.display = "block";
        }, false);
      }

      // iterate through each span element for each modal
      for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
        span[i].onclick = function(){
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      }

      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
          }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you test this script? Or have you got a working example to share?